# AdminLTE dashboard calendar not show at blade laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, bootstrap-4, calendar

I want a nice calendar like this [calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RkcF.png) but what I got is like this [calendar not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNAPa.png). I tried to remove dashboard.js from adminlte and change with bootstrap datetimepicker but still not showing calendar. in dashboard.js (adminlte) that calendar code is just this

```js
$('#calendar').datepicker({
    format: 'L',
    inline: true
  })
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<input type="date" name="name" id="calendar" class="form-control">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and still not working. even I just copy-paste index.html to my dashboard.blade.php and included all adminlte assets there still not showing calendar.

Okay, thanks for the comment now it's working... I just put a specific calendar script in my view from dashboard.js. Thanks all :)

Comment: Please provide full code snippet.

Comment: Check console for errors. Make sure you're passing right options to the plugin. Inspect the calendar and try to see if there's any clashing css, i once had a case where a calendar plugins css was overridden by another plugin which caused calendar to not show.

Comment: Check your question now.

Comment: There're an error in the console, it prevent form initialization the calendar plugin

Comment: are you include datepicker plugins properly

Comment: What script did you add? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Just make sure element selector and datepicker component is correct.. @HeidyMiguel